# Set-builder notation for set generation based on a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have the following function:

$$v(n) = \sqrt{n}$$

I want to generate a set of outputs from the above function, where the input $n$ ranges from $a \rightarrow b$. Is there a set-builder notation for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A first pass might be to write
$$\{ \sqrt{n} \mid a \le n \le b \}$$
which can be written equivalently as
$$\{ m \mid m = \sqrt{n} \text{ for some } a \le n \le b \}$$